# a question about transformation from an article

Tags: probability-theory

I have a question from a proof in an article: 
http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/956/Resource/MultipleComparision/Simes86pdf.pdf

I was reading the above article and tried to understand the proof of the theorem on page 2. The part that I don't understand is how the author comes up with $\alpha(n-1)/(pn)$ inside the bracket beside the term $A(n-1)$. I believe it must be using some kind of transformation but I am not sure how to get $j\alpha/n$ to $\alpha(n-1)/(pn)$ because it was using $P(j)> j\alpha/n$ in the statement of the theorem. But then it becomes $\alpha (n-1)/(pn)$ after the transformation of each of $P(1), P(2), \dots ,P(n-1)$ by turning it to $P(1)/P(n), P(2)/P(n),\dots$?

Thank you to whoever that can help with this.